# How to save Mimedata to a file

Tags: qt, qt5

I have been trying to serialize my tree structure and restore it back with not much of success.

Mimedata function is able to store the tree structure in the correct hierarchy.

How can i save the mime data to a file and load it back to QDataStream ?

```
QMimeData *TreeModel::mimeData(const QModelIndexList  &indexes) const
{
    QMimeData *mimeData = new QMimeData;
    QByteArray data; 
    QDataStream stream(&data, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    QList<TreeItem *> nodes;
    foreach(const QModelIndex &index, indexes) {
        TreeItem *node = getItem(index);
        if (!nodes.contains(node))
            nodes << node;
    }
    stream << QCoreApplication::applicationPid();
    stream << nodes.count();
    foreach(TreeItem *node, nodes) {
        buildTree(node, stream);
    }
    mimeData->setData(s_treeNodeMimeType, data);
    return mimeData;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must implement the stream operators between QDataStream and QMimeData saving the formats and data associated with each format and the number of formats.

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets>

QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &stream, const QMimeData &data)
{
    const QStringList formats = data.formats();
    stream << static_cast<qint32>(formats.size());
    for(const QString& format : formats)
        stream << format << data.data(format);
    return stream;
}

QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &stream, QMimeData &data)
{
    data.clear();
    qint32 size;
    QString format;
    QByteArray formatData;
    stream >> size;
    while(size-->0){
        stream >> format >> formatData;
        data.setData(format,formatData);
    }
    return stream;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    const QString text = "Text";
    const QString html = R"(<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
)";
    const QList<QUrl> urls = {
        {"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58073079/how-to-save-mimedata-to-a-file"},
        {"https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/"}
    };

        const QString mimeType = "custom/custom-app";
    const QByteArray data("stackoverflow");

    const QString path = "datastream.dat";

    {

        QMimeData mimedata;
        mimedata.setText(text);
        mimedata.setHtml(html);
        mimedata.setUrls(urls);
        mimedata.setData(mimeType, data);

        QFile file(path);
        file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
        QDataStream out(&file);
        out << mimedata;
    }

    {

        QMimeData mimedata;
        QFile file(path);
        file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
        QDataStream out(&file);
        out >> mimedata;

        Q_ASSERT(mimedata.text() == text);
        Q_ASSERT(mimedata.html() == html);
        Q_ASSERT(mimedata.urls() == urls);
        Q_ASSERT(mimedata.data(mimeType) == data);
    }

    return 0;
}
```